# Ergodic if and only if time average of measure of intersection equals product of measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to prove the following from Brin and Stuck, exercise 4.5.1:

> > Let $T$ be a measure-preserving transformation of a finite measure space $(X, \mathfrak A, \mu)$. Prove that $T$ is ergodic if and only if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu\left(T^{-k}(A) \cap B\right) = \mu(A) \cdot \mu(B)$$ for any $A, B \in \mathfrak A$.

I'm trying to use the following corollary of the Birkhoff ergodic theorem: that if $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation of a finite measure space $(X, \mathfrak A, \mu)$, then $T$ is ergodic if and only if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_A \left(T^k(x)\right) = \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(X)}.$$ It seems straightforward, but I'm missing a factor of $\mu(X)$ somewhere and I can't find where.

**My strategy:** Let $A, B \in \mathfrak A$. Define the measurable functions $$f_n(x) = \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_A \left(T^k(x)\right) = \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_{T^{-k}(A)}(x).$$ Clearly $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ for all $n$, and by the above corollary to the Birkhoff ergodic theorem, this sequence of functions converges $\mu$-a.e. pointwise to $\mu(A)/\mu(X)$. So by the dominated convergence theorem, we get
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu\left(T^{-k}(A) \cap B\right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_X \chi_{T^{-k}(A)}(x)\cdot \chi_B(x) \,d\mu \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_B \chi_A \circ T^k \,d\mu\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \int_B \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(X)} \,d\mu \\
&= \frac{\mu(A)\cdot\mu(B)}{\mu(X)},
\end{align}
where equality $(*)$ follows if and only if $T$ is ergodic, by the corollary to the Birkhoff ergodic theorem and by dominated convergence.

But there must be a mistake somewhere, and I can't find it; similar results suggest the problem should be true regardless of whether $\mu(X) = 1$. Was I supposed to multiply by a factor of $\mu(X)$ somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nothing is wrong with your computations**, simply Brin and Stuck assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure.

Indeed, if you take $B=X$ in
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu\left(T^{-k}(A) \cap B\right) = \mu(A) \mu(B),
$$
then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(T^{-k}(A)) = \mu(A) \mu(X),
$$
but the left-hand side is equal to $\mu(A)$.

Comment: is there also an other way of proving $T$ ergodic $\Rightarrow $ $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu\left(T^{-k}(A) \cap B\right) = \mu(A) \cdot \mu(B)$ without using the corollary?

Comment: @user123234 I don't know any (somehow the form of ergodicity in the corollary seems unavoidable).

Comment: Okey but can you tell me how to prove the corollary? Is it difficult?

Comment: @user123234 Not difficult, you have to approximate integrable functions by simple functions and take the limit carefully. But it doesn't fit the commentaries.

Comment: okey, is the proof somewhere so that I can look at it if I'm stuck?

Comment: @user123234 I looked at a few places, but I couldn't find a written proof. You can write down the details yourself proceeding in a similar way to that in the proof of Proposition 2.1 in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-28090-0